# Any situation where long is preferred over int when sizeof(int)=sizeof(long)

Tags: c++, c

My desktop and laptop machines have 64 bit and 32 bit Ubuntu 10.10's running on them respectively. I use the `gcc` compiler

Now on my desktop machine I observe that `sizeof(long)=8` while on my laptop `sizeof(long)=4`.

On machines such as my laptop where `sizeof(int) =sizeof(long)=4` are there any situations where would I would prefer `long` over `int` even though they cover the same range of integers?

On my desktop of course `long` would be advantageous if I want a larger range of integers (though of course I could have used `int64_t` or `long long` for that also)

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Why not post that comment as an answer?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: I will upvote you if you make that an answer.

Comment: @Alf: that's the best part of SO -- trolls get downvoted and their answers fall off the deep end of the list.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, *this* is really bad advice. The sematic typedef's (`size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `uint64_t` etc) are there just for the reason that you don't have to go into such considerations.

Comment: @Jens, the typedefs are there for when you need additional guarantees. that was not the question though. for your question (which is a different one), you have to weight the pros and cons of the types involved in your question, instead of in the OP's question. general `int` is practically guaranteed to be efficient, but not to have any particularly large range, while `ptrdiff_t` is the result type of pointer subtraction and practically guaranteed to be large enough for any such subtraction (formally one is in UB-land if it isn't), but is not practically guaranteed to be as efficient as `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use either of them. In modern C (starting with C89) or C++ there are `typedef` that have a semantic that helps you to write portable code. `int` is almost always wrong, the only use case that I still have for that is the return value of library functions. Otherwise use

- `bool` or `_Bool` for Booleans (if you have C++ or C99, otherwise use a `typedef`)
- `enum` for applicative case distinction
- `size_t` for counting and indexing
- unsigned types when you use integers for bit patterns
- `ptrdiff_t` (if you must) for differences of addresses

If you really have an application use for a signed integer type, use either `intmax_t` to have the most and to be on the safe end, or one of the `intXX_t` to have a type with well defined precision and arithmetic.

*Edit*: If your main concern is performance with some minimum width guarantee use the "least" or "fast" types, e.g `int_least32_t`. On all platforms that I programmed so far there was not much of a difference between the precise width types and the "least" types, but who knows.

Comment: I do not agree with the advice to always use the `intXX_t` types.  In almost all cases, what is required is a *minimum* range, and the base types provide this just fine.  There are times when the exact-width types are useful, but this is generally when serialising/deserialising data (eg from a file or a network socket).

Comment: @caf take `XX` as `_leastYY` :) you are right, I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

On a 32-bit OS, where `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)==4` an `int` and a `long` offer the same services.

But, for portability reasons (if you compile your code in 64-bit for example), since an `int` will stay at 32-bit while a `long` can be either 32 or 64-bit, you should use types that fit a constant size to avoid overflows.

For this purpose, the `<stdint.h>` header declares non-ambiguous types like:

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t

intptr_t
```

Where `intptr_t` / `uintptr_t` can represent pointers better than a `long` (the common `sizeof(long)==sizeof(void*)` assumption is not always true).

`time_t` and `size_t` are also types defined to make it easier to write portable code without wondering about the platform specifications.

Just make sure that, when you need to allocate memory, you use `sizeof` (like `sizeof(size_t)`) instead of assuming that a type has any given (hardcoded) value.

Answer (score 1):

While it certainly isn't a *common* practice, the Linux kernel source makes the assumption that pointers -- any pointer to any type -- can fit entirely inside an `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alf noted above, you might choose either int or long for portability reasons.

- On older, 16-bit operating systems, int was 16-bit and long was 32-bit;
- On 32-bit Unix, DOS, and Windows (or 64-bit processors running 32-bit programs), int and long are 32-bits;
- On 64-bit Unix, int is 32-bits, while long is 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

For portability reasons you should use a `long` if you need more than 16 bits and up to 32 bits of precision.  That's really all there is to it - if you know that your values won't exceed 16 bits, then `int` is fine.